# Debug.WriteLine alternative in PhpStorm / PHP (IntelliJ). Am using remote Xdebug

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm looking for a C# `Debug.Writeline` / JavaScript `console.log` alternative in PhpStorm / IntelliJ or a `Debugger.break` perhaps.

Comment: *"or a Debugger.break perhaps."* -- sure, use [xdebug_break()](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions) -- Xdebug must be enabled in your PHP and IDE configure to accept incoming connections (already listen on Xdebug port).

Comment: *"C# Debug.Writeline / JavaScript console.log"* Just write to a standard or custom log file (e.g. `error_log($message, 3, $logFile);` for custom file or `error_log($message);` for standard error log). If no log file is required -- just write using standard file functions to [php://stderr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) then it's up to an IDE if it supports ERROR output channel (AFAIK PhpStorm does support it for CLI debug).

Comment: If you want to write into actual Chrome browser's console, check https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger (suitable for web page debug only via Google Chrome, results will be printed in Console tab similar to `console.log`).